# Does $\widehat{M}\ (\vec{a}\times\vec{b})=\widehat{M}\ \vec{a}\times\widehat{M}\ \vec{b}$?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Is it true to write that $\widehat{M}\ (\vec{a}\times\vec{b})=\widehat{M}\ \vec{a}\times\widehat{M}\ \vec{b}$? If so, how can this be proven?

Comment: False. Let M be the matrix of a projection onto a plane. Also the equation is not homogeneous.

Comment: Why not try a few cases?

Comment: The actual rule is $M^T[Ma\times Mb]=\det M(a\times b)$, so if $M$ is invertible $Ma\times Mb=\det M(M^{-1T})(a\times b)$. As @Somos noted, it needs to be homogeneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true: consider
$M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, $\vec{a} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\vec{b} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.